# Changing the style of the standard android.R.layout options?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to override the standard layouts that are provided with Android? Is it for example possible to make the text smaller for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked? Or would I simply need to make my own layout to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your own layout. In order to make a custom layout and use a standard adapter (like ArrayAdapter) you have to specifiy the same id(s) in your custom layout as in the standard layouts. For example the TextView in simple_list_item_checked has the id "@android:id/text1" (http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_checked.xml.shtml). In your custom layout you specify that id. Thus you do not have to write a custom adapter. So the best way is just by copying the standard xml layout and change what you wanne change

Comment: Thanks. What could go wrong when you give a different id (or no id) than what's in the standard layouts though? I copied the simple_list_item_checked layout and removed the id completely and it still seems to work fine when I load it like this: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.custom_checked_list, arraylist); setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Yes you are right because the "layout" == a TextView. But with other standard layouts this should not work..I mean layouts that consist of more than one view within a LayoutManager e.g LinearLayout maybe

Comment: +1 Good point from you. Had a look at adapters implementation. ArrayAdapter does not care about the id if the adapter wasn't initiated with a textViewResourceId. When no resource id is supplied the adapter assumes that the _whole_ ressource is a TextView. Otherwise the adapter searches for the given resource id (finViewById) (see ArrayAdapter impl https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Here's a similar thing being accomplished (res/values/styles.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="ContactLabelTextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="questionTableRow">
      <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_border</item>
  </style> 
</resources>
```

And then, when you want to apply the style to an element in the layout file that you have created (main.xml, res/layout/your_custom_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableRow
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/questionTableRow"
        style="@style/questionTableRow"
```

Obviously you are looking to accomplish this with a textView. I provided an example of my own code where the textView gets a specific style. I actually don't even have that textView style applied, but I pasted in where I applied a style to a tableRow, just so you see how to apply it to an xml element.

Does this do what you need?

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping not to have to make my own layout file but to somehow inherit android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked and then override only the particular values I want to change (in this case text size), but in this example you've created your own styles from scratch. So far it's looking like you can't directly alter the standard layouts in android.R.layout, you need to make your version of it as written by 207.